# How to get the x position of SKEL_HEAD kinect?

Tags: arduino, processing, kinect

I am coding a installation with Arduino, Processing and Kinect. 
What I want is get the x-as of SKEL_HEAD from the example code of Processing Kinect User.

Later I want to map the x-as of my head to 180 degrees servo motor.

What I have now is, I draw a red circle on my head when Kinect is active.

```
void drawSkeleton(int userId) {
  // to get the 3d joint data
  /*
  PVector jointPos = new PVector();
  context.getJointPositionSkeleton(userId,SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_NECK,jointPos);
  println(jointPos);
  */

  // Get X position of HEAD
  PVector jointPos = new PVector();
  context.getJointPositionSkeleton(userId, SimpleOpenNI.SKEL_HEAD, jointPos);
  println("jointPos " + jointPos);

  PVector jointPos2d = new PVector();
  context.convertRealWorldToProjective(jointPos,jointPos2d);  


  fill(255,0,0); // Fill the shape
  ellipse(jointPos2d.x, jointPos2d.y, 40,40); // Create the shape
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. Calling `convertRealWorldToProjective` should convert the 3d coordinates to 2d coordinates. What I wonder is if this is the mapping you want: 2d position of the head instead of rotation of the head on Y axis ?

If you want to map the rotation of the head you should be able to decompose the 3D transformation matrix for the head joint, although I'm not sure how accurate that will be. There are [other ways](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~gfanelli/head_pose/head_forest.html) of getting the head orientation  if that doesn't work.

If 2D position mapped to servo position is what you're after, for as long as the skeleton you're after after is tracked it should be a matter is simply calling the [map()](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) function to align the position range (probably 0-640px depending on your kinect setup to 0-180 depending on your servo setup - the values may be offset a bit.

It's probably going to be handy to draw a top down view where you map the position of the head in a flat plane to the servo rotation. It sounds a bit a like a look-at scenario, where the servo need to turn so an object faces a head 2d position.